# Why Beans are not loaded from spring-servlet.xml file?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working with springMVC ,I configure my beans in spring-servlet.xml file but when I am trying to do @Autowired it's giving bean not found exception.Any one help me ,Please check my code below

**Pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
    <javax.mail.version>1.5.2</javax.mail.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <javax.servlet.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
    <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.9.13</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
    <commons-codec.version>1.8</commons-codec.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    <spring.ws.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <javax.jsp-api.version>2.1</javax.jsp-api.version>
    <commons-httpclient.version>3.1</commons-httpclient.version>
    <apache.commons.version>1.3.2</apache.commons.version>
    <javax.jstl.version>1.2</javax.jstl.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>

     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jsp-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-mapper-asl.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For apache IOUtils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.45</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
    <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true" />
    <property name="connectionManagerClass"
        value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="errorHandler">

        <bean class="com.test.TemplateErrorHandler" />

    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="json" />
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="Emp" class="com.test.Emp" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Emp**

```
 public class Emp{
     private String fname;
     //seeter,getter methods.
  }
```

**TestClass**

```
 @Service
 public TestClass 
{
     @Autowired
     private Emp emp;

}
```

while doing autowire I am getting exception.

```
  **web.xml**


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee                           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>mytest</display-name>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

> Note:But when I configure Emp class with (@component) it is working fine
>
> ```
>     @Component
>    public class Emp{
>      private String fname;
>      //seeter,getter methods.
>   } It is working fine
> ```

any one help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is named `spring-servlet.xml` and your dispatcher servlet is `servlet`. But you explicitely declare in web.xml that you use an `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` scanning package `com.test`, so :

- `spring-servlet.xml` is ignored and no bean defined in it are used
- `@Component` (or other spring annotations) classes are loaded as beans

As you have an explicit `<context:component-scan base-package="com" />` in `spring-servlet.xml`, you should use the default application context (a `XmlWebApplicationContext`) and simply put in web.xml for the `<servlet>` bloc :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

to use a `XmlWebApplicationContext` reading `spring-servlet.xml` (provided it lies under `WEB-INF` folder).

Answer (score 0):

Edited your web.xml, try,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
      <display-name>mytest</display-name>
      <servlet>
         <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
           <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
           <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
           </param-value>
         </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <session-config>
       <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
     /session-config>
```

Comment: AFAIK, an AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext only read `@Configuration` classes (or can scan packages for them) but does not directly accept xml configuration files. You should use a `@Configuration` class to import it.